# Если значение ячейки больше Х, но меньше У, то...

Tags: excel

Здравствуйте.
На форуме я нашел похожее решение, но моя задача несколько сложнее.
К сожалению я не нашел способа сделать вложение, а так будет труднее объяснить, но я попробую.
Итак, допустим есть три цеха. У каждого есть плановое задание на год и раз в месяц они отчитываются о выполнении плана. Допустим для первого цеха А1 - план на год, А2 - выполнение нарастающим итогом, А3 - процент выполнения. Для второго цеха эти значения в В1, В2, В3 и для третьего С1, С2, С3. Задача автоматического расчета состоит в том, чтобы выявить плохишей, отстающих от выполнения плана и принять меры к ним: либо наказание за плохую работу, либо оказание помощи в случае затруднений. Но я отвлекся...
Формула должна сравнивать поквартально, в зависимости от текущей даты процент выполнения, например
="Отстают от выполнения плана - "&ЕСЛИ(МЕСЯЦ(СЕГОДНЯ())<3;ЕСЛИ(А3=0;"1 цех работы не выполнял";"");ЕСЛИ(МЕСЯЦ(СЕГОДНЯ())>=3, но <=6;ЕСЛИ(А3<25%;"1 цех";"");))... и так далее

Comment: Похоже, что это вопрос по Excel, а не по регулярным выражениям.

Comment: Проверьте правильность выбора метки.

Comment: можно на любом языке написать алгоритм, но если поподробнее знать условия.

Comment: На VBA можно макрос написать

Comment: На VBA можно макрос написать

Можно-то можно, только я в макросах - ноль. Разве что макрорекодером

Comment: В любом случае для написания рабочего кода нужна полная постановка задачи.

Comment: Как я уже писал, я не нашел как тут прикладывать файл-пример.
Да и потом, ну напишете Вы код, а дальше что? Мне же его надо будет править в случае изменений

Comment: Если можете макрорекордером, то запишите им. Если нет, то нужно полное условие.

Comment: И все-таки хотелось бы формулой...
Подскажите, как прикрепить к сообщению файл-пример

Comment: Если файл не картинка, то нужно залить его на файлообменник и вставить в сообщение ссылку.

Comment: Вот ссылка для скачивания
http://yadi.sk/d/0YuJ4prU71pXa

Разумеется это только часть файла. На самом деле в таблице 80 пунктов и 18 цехов.

Comment: как вариант, можно купить плеть и пороть плохишей помогая производству и закаляя организм одновременно